# MySQL Case Count

Tags: mysql, count, case

Hi I'm having a confusion on how to do this query.

I have tables:

```
transactiondetails
-> TransactionDetailsID
-> TerminalID
-> SiteID
-> TransactionType
-> Amount

terminals
-> TerminalID
-> TerminalName
-> TerminalType
```

Now, on table terminals.TerminalType the values is either 0 or 1.
In my transactiondetails I need to find the total number of terminals.TerminalType = 1 in a particular SiteID in the table
transactiondetails so my query is

```
SELECT 
CASE 
WHEN b.TerminalType IN (1) then COUNT(a.TerminalID)
ELSE 0 END AS TotalGenesis, a.SiteID
FROM npos.transactiondetails a
LEFT JOIN npos.terminals b ON a.TerminalID = b.TerminalID 
WHERE a.SiteID = 167;
```

But I got zero result for TotalGenesis even if I have a TerminalType = 1 in my transactiondetails.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: In MySQL you can write `COUNT (TerminalType  = 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query. Instead of using `IN` use equal(=) sign. See Below:

```
SELECT 
      CASE 
          WHEN b.TerminalType = 1 THEN COUNT(a.TerminalID)
          ELSE 0 
      END AS TotalGenesis, 
      a.SiteID
FROM npos.transactiondetails a
LEFT JOIN npos.terminals b ON a.TerminalID = b.TerminalID 
WHERE a.SiteID = 167;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the join is failing? That would cause it to return zero. Are you sure TerminalType isn't null?

Do either of these queries return the correct result?

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN b.TerminalType IN (1) then COUNT(a.TerminalID)
        ELSE 0
    END AS TotalGenesis,
    a.SiteID
FROM npos.transactiondetails a
LEFT JOIN npos.terminals b ON a.TerminalID = b.TerminalID 
WHERE a.SiteID = 167
GROUP BY a.SiteID;

SELECT 
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN b.TerminalType IN (1) then 1
        ELSE 0
    END) AS TotalGenesis,
    a.SiteID
FROM npos.transactiondetails a
LEFT JOIN npos.terminals b ON a.TerminalID = b.TerminalID 
WHERE a.SiteID = 167;
```

Either way it appears that you want an inner join and not a left join.